# Using Enumerable#zip on an Array of Arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, enumerable

I am trying to use `Enumerable#zip` on an array of arrays in order to group the elements of the first nested array with the corresponding elements of each subsequent nested array. This is my array:

```
roster = [["Number", "Name", "Position", "Points per Game"],
          ["12","Joe Schmo","Center",[14, 32, 7, 0, 23] ],
          ["9", "Ms. Buckets ", "Point Guard", [19, 0, 11, 22, 0] ],
          ["31", "Harvey Kay", "Shooting Guard", [0, 30, 16, 0, 25] ], 
          ["7", "Sally Talls", "Power Forward", [18, 29, 26, 31, 19] ], 
          ["22", "MK DiBoux", "Small Forward", [11, 0, 23, 17, 0] ]]
```

I want to group "Number" with "12", "9", "31", "7", and "22", and then do the same for "Name", "Position", etc. using zip. The following gives me the output I want:

```
roster[0].zip(roster[1], roster[2], roster[3], roster[4], roster[5])
```

How can I reformat this so that if I added players to my roster, they would be automatically included in the `zip` without me having to manually type in `roster[6]`, `roster[7]`, etc. I've tried using ranges in a number of ways but nothing seems to have worked yet.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First extract the head and tail of the list (header and rows, respectively) using a splat, then [`zip`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) them together:

```
header, *rows = roster
header.zip(*rows)
```

This is the same as using [`transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Array.html#method-i-transpose) on the original `roster`:

```
header, *rows = roster
zipped = header.zip(*rows)

roster.transpose == zipped  #=> true
```

Comment: Thanks - both of your suggestions worked. I agree, transpose was the appropriate method I just wasn't aware of its existence.

Answer (score 2):

```
:zip.to_proc[*roster]
```

a bit more flexible than `transpose`:

`:zip.to_proc[*[(0..2), [:a, :b, :c]]] #=> [[0, :a], [1, :b], [2, :c]]`

Comment: Nice, it also supports different-sized lists. `:zip.to_proc[*[[1,2],[4,5,6]]]` -> `[[1, 4], [2, 5]]` whereas transpose gives an error: `IndexError: element size differs (3 should be 2)`

Answer (score 1):

```
p roster.transpose()
```

.......................

Comment: This lacks detail. Please elaborate.

Comment: After the variable name 'roster', type a dot then a 't', then an 'r', then and 'a', then an 'n', then an 's', then a 'p', then an 'o', then an 's', then an 'e'.  To output variables you can use puts or p, which stands for 'inspect'.  If you output an array with puts, it will print each element of the array on a newline, which makes it difficult to figure out what is going on.  If you output an array with p, it shows you the elements of the array separated by commas and with brackets around the array.

Comment: Ruby is a language invented by Yukihiro Matsumoto, a Japanese computer scientist, who was born on 14 April 1965, and ruby has recently seen a version 2.x release.  transpose() is a ruby method, and it is a method of the Array class.  puts and p are private methods of the Kernel module, but because the Object class includes the Kernel module, puts and p can be called anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
roster[0].zip(*(roster[1..-1]))
```

Doesn't matter how many are in the roster array.

Comment: I suppose this was down-voted by the same person who down-voted the perfectly elegant answer below. The OP already understands the `zip` method. They just said they had tried all sorts of ranges and couldn't make it work. There are already other good answers here, I was merely showing how a range CAN work no matter the number of players they adds later.